# Sample size for EFA

Tags: factor-analysis, sample-size, exploratory-data-analysis

Looked but could not find so I apologize if this is a repeat of a question already asked -

Can I conduct an EFA with an N of 180 and 70 variables?  I say NO but my advisor still wants me to do it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know of no reason why not. EFA is based on the correlation matrix, so, while larger samples may yield more precisely estimated correlations, you don't run into the overfitting problems that you would with regression.

Comment: So the sample size rules or variable to N ratio found in texts are just archaic guidelines?  Just wondering, after reading the de Winter article from 2009 - seems like the rules are old!

Comment: Not srue which ratios you are talking about or for what procedures. What's in the de Winter article?